# Shift and scale a set of vectors to align them: $a_i \mathbf x_i + b_i = a_j\mathbf x_j + b_j$ for all $i,j$

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization, least-squares

Align a set of vectors with shifting and scaling:

Given a set of vectors $\mathbf x_1, \cdots, \mathbf x_N$ in $\mathbb R^n$, find pairs of real numbers $(a_1, b_1), \cdots, (a_N, b_N)$ (scaling and shifting parameters) such that $ | (a_i \mathbf x_i + b_i) - (a_j \mathbf x_j + b_j) | $ is minimal for all $i,j$.
Here summing a real value to the vector is done element-wise.

How should I approach this problem?

What I tried is to simply get the mean vector $\bar {\mathbf x}$ and then solve $N$ least squares problems $a_i \mathbf x_i + b_i = \bar {\mathbf x}$ but I'm not sure this is the optimal approach.

**Edit:** Ok so a friend pointed out that there's the trivial solution $a_i = b_i = 0$ which is not what I was aiming for. In a way, I wish to *calibrate* each vector with the least amount of scaling and shifting ($a_i \approx 1, b_i \approx 0$) so that they all align.

**Edit2:** Imagine I have a set of rulers with marks, but let's say the ruler manufacturer is not very good so the marks across rulers are misaligned. I'd like to stretch each ruler or shift the marks so that they all align.

Comment: Are the vectors $\mathbf{x}_i$ of the same length? If not, what's more important, the length or the direction? where would you want a small vector to match with a larger one, at its root or the middle or...? Note that $a\mathbf{x}+b$ does not make sense, unless you meant $b$ to be vectors.

Comment: They are not of the same length. And the norm of interest you can take it as $L^2$ for the moment. As for $a\mathbf x +b$, I wrote in the question that it is added element-wise.

Comment: As things stand, the effect of $b$ is not to shift but to drag one endpoint of $x$. Secondly, the minimum would be $0$ by choosing all $a$ and $b$ to be zero.

Comment: By shifting I meant $\mathbf x + b = (x_1 + b, x_2 + b, \cdots, x_n + b)$. What do you mean by dragging? And yes, I edited my question yesterday as someone also pointed out to me the trivial solution.

Comment: I need to think more about how to state the problem properly. What I really want is to align a set of vectors with the least "deformation" possible. Imagine I have a set of rulers with marks, but let's say the ruler manufacturer is not very good so the marks across rulers are misaligned. I'd like to stretch each ruler or shift the marks so that they all align.

Comment: By your definition, $(1,0)+10 = (11,10)$. The vector has changed in direction and magnitude. It is not what we would normally call 'shift'. Shifting a vector in the usual sense would keep its magnitude and direction preserved. Your second comment raises more questions: 1. Are the directions of the rulers important? Can you align them and *then* shift and stretch them? 2. Are the markings of each ruler equally spaced?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. How is it possible to shift a vector while keeping its magnitude _and_ direction? Can you provide an example? Regarding the second point: 1) If I understand correctly directions don't matter here 2) By "aligning the rulers" I actually mean aligning the marks, 3) No, not equally spaced. For example ruler $\mathbf x_1 = (1, 2, 3)$, ruler $\mathbf x_2 = (2, 3, 5)$, ruler $\mathbf x_3 = (0, 3, 7)$. Here, $(1,2,3)$ would be the "marks".

Comment: Now as you mentioned the trivial solution that I missed (and which I'm trying to avoid) is to multiply all the vectors to 0, then "all marks are aligned". But actually, I'm looking to somehow minimize the stretching/compressing as much as possible.

Comment: I will take some time to re-edit the whole question as I now realize I did a terrible job in terms of terminology. I use "align" which brings to mind directionality, which is not useful here. I should re-write the whole thing later.

Comment: Ok, that makes much more sense now. The question can be recast as: given a 'standard' ruler $\mathbf{u}$ (say $(1,2,\ldots,n)$), and a vector $\mathbf{x}$, how to find $a,b$ such that $|a\mathbf{x}+b-\mathbf{u}|$ is minimised. If there is no standard, then pick an arbitrary vector and take *its* parameters to be $a=1$ and $b=0$. You would also need to minimise some sum $\sum_i|a_i\mathbf{x}_i+b_i|^2$. Please take some time to edit the question until it can be answered.

Comment: I've thought about this a bit more. You can plot each vector $\mathbf{x}$ as $(i,x_i)$ and find the regression line through these points. That gives a slope $m$ and intercept $c$. Then to collimate the vectors, take $a=1/m$ and $b=-c/m$. There is no unique way of doing this - you can multiply $a$ by any fixed number and add to $b$ any fixed number. Can you see if this solves the problem?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion and sorry for the late reply. So if I understand correctly your solution essentially amounts to regressing each vector onto the vector $(1,2,3,...,n)$, correct? I'm not sure about this because my vectors are not necessarily close to $(1,2,3,...,n)$. It can be e.g. $(-0.123, 2.7, -0.5)$, but it's also true that all the vectors are already "more or less close", e.g. another vector in the set can be $(-0.122, 3, -0.4)$. My current solution was to regress each vector onto the mean vector instead.

Comment: I think your procedure is optimal, assuming that the mean of $a_i$ is $1$ and of $b_i$ is $0$, which simply fixes the scale and shift factors. The only problem I see is that a random large scaling factor $a$ would skew the larger values of $x$. In theory large values of $a$ are balanced off by small values, but in practice they don't.